# How do you calculate what percentage of a file has been output in C?

Tags: c

Hey guys so i'm trying to write my own 'more' command, the problem i'm having however is how to output the percentage of the file that has been read (like the original 'more' command). The only way I can think of doing this is by getting the number of lines in the file and doing some calculation to calculate this percentage every time the user enters a command ('enter' key to display an additional single line at a time, 'space' key to display 23 lines at a time). Is there a simple way to do this? If not, anyone have a clue as how to go about doing this calculation? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks, i went ahead and got the file size using stat

```
struct stat st;
int fileSize;
stat(argv[1], &st);
fileSize = (int)st.st_size;
```

now I just need to figure out how to get the number of bytes that have been read/output so far so i can calculate the percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of lines in a file, you will need to preprocess the entire file to get that information.

If you want the number of bytes in a file, you can get that information from [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) or [`fstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Answer (score 2):

"stat" the file or open and seek to the end to get the size in bytes, then simply track the bytes output / total bytes.

All IO output functions in C stdio return the amount of data written.

```
while((count = write(...)) > 0) {
   tot += count;
   pct = count * 100 / tot;
}
```